# Grab xPath content without surrounding markup

Tags: xpath

How do you grab the content of xPath without copying the surrounding mark?

```
<div id="node-123" class="clearfix">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="body">
                            <p><img src="/images/image.jpg"/></p>
                            <p>Some content ....</p>
                        </div>    
                    </div>
                </div>
```

If I used `//div[@id='node-123']/div/div`, I still get surrounding `<div class="body">` which is not expected.

What I want is the content of `<div class="body">`, excluding this `<div class="body">` markup, but reserving other markups inside the content, p, img, etc.

I tried to use wildcard: `//div[@id='node-123']/div/div/*`, but this only fetch the first `p`, where `p` can be two or many. Using node() fetch nothing.

Any hint would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It is a strange, because I've just test `//div[@id='node-123']/div/div/*` at http://xpath.online-toolz.com/tools/xpath-editor.php and it return 2 paragraphs for me. May be problem not in XPath expression, but how you fetch results?

Comment: indeed, the result of message test also returns 2 paragraphs, but when it comes to the WYSIWYG editor, it returns the first paragraph, only. Somehow somewhere trimmed by ckeditor. I used http://drupal.org/project/feeds_xpathparser drupal 7 module.

Comment: I found the problem with unterminated img tag at actual original article: `<img src="/images/image.jpg">` rather than `<img src="/images/image.jpg"/>.` My.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I used
>   `//div[@id='node-123']/div/div`, I
>   still get surrounding `<div
>   class="body">` which is not expected.
>
> What I want is the content of `<div
>   class="body">`, excluding this `<div
>   class="body">` markup, but reserving
>   other markups inside the content, `p`,
>   `img`, etc.

**Use**:

```
//div[@id='node-123']/div/div/node()
```

This selects all nodes (elements, text-nodes, processing-instructions and comment-nodes) that are children of any `div` element that is a child of any `div` element that is a child of any `div` element in the document such that the value of its `id` attribute is 'node-123'.

**Warning**: **It is always a good practice not to use the `//` pseudo-operator** if the structure of the XML document is statically known. Using the `//` pseudo -operator results most-often in very slow performance, causing complete tree traversal.

Comment: Test results using node() displayed as expected, strangely it is not stored into textarea as expected. Assumed something wrong with the parser. Also with or without tidy behave strangely. Strange, but thanks for node() explanations.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is unterminated img tag at actual original article: `<img src="/images/image.jpg">` rather than `<img src="/images/image.jpg"/>.`